# How can I start and Activity from a class extending ItemizedOverlay?

Tags: android

I have a class that extends ItemizedOverlay.

In it, I have:

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  /*// working below code, just replace */
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new
  AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.setPositiveButton("Details",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


 }
  });
```

When I click the "Details" button, I want to start an Activity or setContentView, but those methods do not exist.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this /*context*/, ExampleActivityClass.class /*Your new Activity Class*/);
i.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
startActivity(i);
```

and you should add an intent-filter to your android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivityClass">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW />
    </intent-filter>    
</activity>
```

For further information see and read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Esentian

Comment: Esentian, 
That makes sense, but the class does not extend Activity, but ItemizedOverlay.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Android but I think you should create Intent to start a new activity (and pass it to Context.startActivity())
.

Answer (score 0):

I defined the class that extended ItemizedOverlay as a private class of the Map Activity, as it was quite specify functionality that wanted to keep with Activity. So methods getApplicationContext() and startActivity() are available.

```
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  selectedItem = mOverlays.get(index);
  Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class);
  i.putExtra(Application.ITEM_KEY, selectedItem));
  startActivity(i);
  return true;
}
```